# How to dynamically link error pages to files in Eclipse using Play! Framework?

Tags: eclipse, playframework

In **application.conf** you have this:

```
# Open file from errors pages
# ~~~~~
# If your text editor supports opening files by URL, Play! will
# dynamically link error pages to files 
#
# Example, for textmate:
play.editor=txmt://open?url=file://%s&line=%s
```

How can I get this working for eclipse?

Comment: Tried to get this up and running however have not been successful yet. It seems that a uri needs to be registered for eclipse to do so. See http://caffeinelab.net/2010/03/11/testing-in-plays-eclipse-plugin/. I followed the description on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/805063 to register such on Linux. This works but always opens a new instance of eclipse instead of opening the file in the eclipse which is already open. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @OliverSauder the first link doesn't seem to work but this should be it: http://caffeinelab.net/blog/2010/03/11/testing-in-plays-eclipse-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Although old and still an incubated project this does the job: [Eclipse Web Interface](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Web_Interface)

Install it, close eclipse and start it again (a restart didn't work for me).

Now you can tell play how to link the errors to eclipse:

```
play.editor=http://localhost:34567/?command=org.eclipse.soc.ewi.examples.commands.openfile&path=%s&line=%s
```

HTH

Comment: Apparently the url needs to be inside double quotes

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to work. However I was able to use Eclipse Web Interface, via https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-framework-tools/dchhggpgbommpcjpogaploblnpldbmen